# How to compare age across multiple groups?

Tags: anova, descriptive-statistics

I have age data on 5 groups, and I would like to compare if one group is significantly older or younger than another. When comparing 2 groups, I can use a 2-sample t-test, but when comparing across multiple groups (5 groups in my case), which statistical test should I use?

Comment: Are the groups related in some ordinal sense (eg, high-school students, college-students, grad-students), or are they unrelated categories (eg, architects, engineers, truck drivers)? Are the ages bumped up against 0 (ie newborns) or are they further from 0 & thus roughly symmetrical?

Comment: @gung The groups are different types of thyroid cancers. The age distributions are mostly normal with mean around 50ish.

Comment: How much data do you have per group?

Comment: The smallest is 100 people. The largest has close to 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run an [ANOVA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) on these data.  If the data weren't sufficiently normal, you could run a [Kruskal-Wallis test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance), but the ANOVA is actually fairly robust and non-normality makes less difference as $n_j$ increases.  You have large $n$ in each group, so the data would have to be very non-normal for the ANOVA to be impacted.

A different issue is whether this is really the question you want to ask.  It may well be, I don't know, but if you are wondering if, e.g., the onset of certain types of cancers occurs later than others, you may want to look into something like a [survival analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis).